# how do I make the scroll in a container start in on a certain link by default?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/jimjamjom/pen/oBoEgz

please see codepen above. Basically when someone visits the page, the container should by default be set to "Section 3" and then they would need to either scroll up or down to see the rest.

I have already tried this and failed.

```
<li class="active">
<a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
</li>
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 $(window).load(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#section3').offset().top}, 1000);
});
});
  </script>
  <style>
  body {
      /*position: relative; */
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}

  </style>
</head>


 <div class="container">
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    
     
    </div>
    <div>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="page">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="page">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="page">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="page">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code when the DOM is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.location.hash = "#" + "section3";
});
```

Check the [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRqXOp)

Comment: added into a <script></script>   see here: https://codepen.io/jimjamjom/pen/oBoEgz    section 3 nav gets activate but The scroll itself doesnt scroll down?

Comment: @topazt The link doesn't contain the jquery code. No js code in the link you gave me.

Comment: @topazt sorry I have made a change and check the pen I posted.

Comment: YES that worked. can i see a bit of the section 2 at the top.(section 3 in the middle with the bottom of section 2 peeping through?"

Comment: @topazt I have updated the pen. Please check if you want that way. If I got you.

Comment: where did you change it? cant see bottom of section 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134238/discussion-between-yonas-hailu-and-topazt).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options the first making your initial http request contain `#section3` [like this](http://codepen.io/jimjamjom/pen/oBoEgz/#section3)

You can also add this to your body

```
<body onload="window.location.href="#section3">
```

Comment: I tried option 2:https://codepen.io/jimjamjom/pen/oBoEgz     link is active to section 3 but the scroll is still sitauted at the top

Answer (score 1):

There are two method to this.

**1. To create a permalink.**

Make the URL to be accessed as `www.myawesomesite.com/#section3`

**2. Scroll the page on load using javascript.**

Add this code to your script.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#section3').offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

It'll scroll the page to the top position of #section3 on page load.

Comment: instead of scrolling the page, can you just scroll the container? https://codepen.io/jimjamjom/full/NdwoZZ/

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure your content is at the very bottom of your page you can add this to the onload function of your page

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```